# Request contains unrecognized parameter:[type] in elastic search while making request for getting suggestion

Tags: node.js, express, elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search in node js + express and i am struggling getting suggestion in elastic search.

Below things, i have completed before making request for es suggestions.

1) I have created es index(name- "movies") and type("movie") and mapping for index.

Index is :

```
return elasticClient.indices.create({
      index:"movies",
      body : {
        "settings" : {
          "index" : {
              "number_of_shards" : 5,
              "number_of_replicas" : 2
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

mapping is :

```
createMovieMapping:function(){
    return elasticClient.indices.putMapping({
      index:"movies",
      type:"movie",
      body:{
          properties:{
            movieName : {type:"string"},
            suggest:{
              type:"completion",
              analyzer:"simple",
              search_analyzer:"simple",
              payloads:true
            }
          }
        }
    })
  }
```

2) Pushed some data from my db to es index "movies" with type "movie".

function for adding data in index :

```
addDataToMovieEsIndex:function(document){
    return elasticClient.index({
      index:"movies",
      type:"movie",
      id:document._id, // for preventing duplicate insertion
      body:{
        movieName:document.movie_name,
        suggest:{
          input : document.movie_name.split(" "),
          output : document.movie_name,
          payload : document
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

3) Now i am trying to get suggestion results with following created function -

```
getMovieSuggestion: function(input){
    elasticClient.suggest({
      index:"movies",
      type:"movie",
      body : {
        moviesuggest:{
          text: input,
          completion:{
            field : "suggest",
            fuzzy : true
          }
        }
      }
    },function(err,resp){
      if(resp){
        console.log('response ',resp)
      }
      if(err){
        console.log('error ',err);        
      }      
    })
  }
```

But i am getting below error while making request for getting suggestions for movie result.

```
{ Error: [illegal_argument_exception] request [/movies/_suggest] contains unrecognized parameter: [type]
    at respond (/Users/siyaram.malav/malav/my_apps/movie-info-app/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:307:15)
    at checkRespForFailure (/Users/siyaram.malav/malav/my_apps/movie-info-app/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:266:7)
    at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/Users/siyaram.malav/malav/my_apps/movie-info-app/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:159:7)
    at IncomingMessage.bound (/Users/siyaram.malav/malav/my_apps/movie-info-app/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
  status: 400,
  displayName: 'BadRequest',
  message: '[illegal_argument_exception] request [/movies/_suggest] contains unrecognized parameter: [type]',
  path: '/movies/_suggest',
  query: { type: 'movie' },
  body: '{"moviesuggest":{"text":"Sultan","completion":{"field":"suggest","fuzzy":true}}}',
```

NOTE: i tried removing the type:"movie" from getMovieSuggestion function then it gives me following error :

```
Error: [illegal_argument_exception] no mapping found for field [suggest]
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use

```
type:"movie"
```

in the call to elasticClient.suggest.

See here for reference, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-suggest

It should just be:

```
getMovieSuggestion: function(input){
    elasticClient.suggest({
      index:"movies",
      body : {
        moviesuggest:{
          text: input,
          completion:{
            field : "suggest",
            fuzzy : true
          }
        }
      }
    },function(err,resp){
      if(resp){
        console.log('response ',resp)
      }
      if(err){
        console.log('error ',err);        
      }      
    })
  }
```

Also, as per the OP's use of ES 5.5, the ES JS API still uses the _suggest endpoint, which is deprecated. The use of the _search endpoint with the appropriate params works as indicated in the comments.

Comment: Hi Animesh thanks for information but i tried that . it gives me error : 
Error: [illegal_argument_exception] no mapping found for field [suggest].

i am following this reference : https://blog.raananweber.com/2015/11/24/simple-autocomplete-with-elasticsearch-and-node-js/

Comment: Hi @SrmHitter9062, Was the mapping sucessfully created? Can you fetch the mapping "movie" for the index "movies" and check. Also, which Elasticsearch version you are using? I see that your API call is using the ES _suggest endpoint which is deprecated in the latest 5.x versions. If you are using Elasticsearch 5.x, then you should set the "apiVersion" config option in the ES Client constructor (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/configuration.html#config-options). The Reference article that you are using used Elasticsearch 2.x with the appropriate JS API

Comment: Mapping was created successfully.
I am using 5.5.0 ES version And yes, it's been deprecated in latest 5.x version.
I tried _search endpoint , it worked:

return elasticClient.search({
      index: 'movies',
      type:"movie",
      body: {
        query: {
          match: {
            movieName: input
          }
        }
      }
    });

But I don't get the idea of setting apiVersion in ES client constructor ?

Comment: I was under the assumption that maybe the call to elasticClient.suggest would use the _search endpoint with the appropriate params, and that's why I wondered whether setting the apiVersion to use the right ES would make it right. I cross-checked in the JS lib code and it doesn't look so - check out https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/blob/master/src/lib/apis/5_5.js#L6768 for ES 5.5. Best would be to continue the way you did it. I edited the answer to reflect the correct way too, Cheers.